# Handling varying API response Dtype

Tags: python, api, response, dtype

Given a basic API call -

```
response = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(key, secret), headers=headers, data=d)
return(response.json())
```

How would you handle the `response` if the Dtype varied? E.g., sometimes `json`, sometimes `.xlsx` [binary]?

**Context:** I want to create a function that tests 3x criteria:

1. **Response is JSON object containing** `percent_complete` - if TRUE, then the `percent_complete` value is used to add to a progress bar. This `apir_response` tells me the requested data isn't ready yet and takes `percent_complete` value to update a progress bar.
2. **Response is JSON object containing** `meta` - if TRUE, then the requested data has been returned as a JSON object, and `api_response` should be returned, ready to be used in another function.
3. **Response is an `.xlsx` file (binary??)** - if TRUE, then the requested data has been returned in `.xlsx` format, and `api_response` should be returned, ready for use in another function.

Any suggestions would be welcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `try` and `except` for that:

```py
response = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(key, secret), headers=headers, data=d)

try:
    data = response.json()
    # No exceptions here means that we get and parse valid json
    if 'percent_complete' in data:
        """Handle option 1 here."""

    elif 'meta' in data:
        """Handle option 2 here."""

    else:
        # Unknown format, so return None
        return None
except:
    # Data is non json, as exception occured
    """Try handling option 3 here by accessing `response.content`."""
```